# New learner question - Why wont my backround color change?

Tags: css

Im very new to web development. Im watching a video where it explains the basics of CSS styling within the HTML file, stuff like changing the color of text, font-size and background color.

Basically my background color wont change. Naturally I've searched around here and google for some answers, I'm sure its something very simple, but I cant quite figure it out on my own. Anyone mind helping me out? It would be greatly appreciated!

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <style>

h1 {
backround-color: blue;
color: red;
font-size: 70px;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;

}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<h1> My name is George and im learning how to do some <a href="https://www.imgur.com" title="web development" target="_blank"> Web Development </a> </h1>
<p> This is a test which I will be attempting to use CSS on, here it goes! </p>

</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo - `background-color`, not `backround-color`

Comment: lol wow thank yoouu!

Comment: @jorgus Make sure you mark an answer or answer yourself, although it looks like someone has already answered.

Comment: You should be using some sort of IDE if you're going to be developing stuff - visual Studio code gets my recommendation

Comment: @Laif - Not really, if an error is caused by a typo the Question should be deleted / closed, because it's not going to be helpful for other people visiting the site; which is mostly the purpose of StackOverflow

Comment: @Light either way, he was unlikely to return to take any action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the spelling you have backround-color: it should be background-color:

Comment: Ok thank you guys, im still trying to figure out how to mark the question as "answered" and so on. Ill also go on and delete this thread as well as download visual studio.

In the future, how do i go about making the post answered status?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers